# If people in medieval times had access to osmium, would it be used?

Tags: weapons, chemistry, armors, metalworking, tools

Let's say that in 1,200 AD, aliens secretly come to Earth and drop off tons of Osmium in various places.The aliens then leave and humans discover this new metal.

By the late medieval era, forges should be powerful enough to melt osmium. If medieval blacksmiths had access to osmium and osmium alloys, would they use osmium in weapons, armor,jewelry, and other metal tools? Osmium is a very hard and dense metal but it is also brittle.

Comment: They would use osmium if the author wanted them to. Please clarify your objectives and what the worldbuilding-problem to solve is. You seem to have your world already built, but want to know about the choices of a group of people. Could you [edit] to identify what the question revolves around other than people's choices? (Which are off-topic)

Comment: Do you mean Richard Osmium from Countdown? Since most Medieval people could not read they would have no use for Osmium I am afraid.

Comment: Forges do not melt anything. Not in the antiquity, not in the middle ages, and not in our days. Melting stuff is not what a forge does. And no, there is no way to melt osmium with medieval technology; at 3033 °C ​(5491 °F) osmium has the third highest melting point among all metals, after tungsten and rhenium. Moreover, osmium is quite difficult to forge or to machine even with modern technology...

Comment: VTC: (a) The [help/dont-ask] states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question." (b) The technological capabilities of Earth circa 476-1450 vary wildly both in time and in location - and you've provided no specific time or location. (c) "would it be used" is a character/organization choice, prohibited in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @JBH, did you read the post. I stated the osmium appeared in 1,200 AD. I also stated possible uses for osmium. I'm just wondering if they are viable.

Comment: @ITM_Coder I apologize for missing that you'd set the date, but that still leaves how you've worded the Q. You're asking us if people would choose to use it. Character choices are off-topic. "Is that viable?" is a terrible question because the answer is always yes - If the off-topic circumstances cause understanding that bring about hoped for goal. If what you were asking is, "how could blacksmiths ca. 1200 AD use osmium to improve armor?" that would be an entirely on-topic question (but only if you asked about armor. If you asked also about weapons, when we're into VTC:NMF territory).

Comment: Please remember, The Stack is here to help you resolve a problem that's keeping you from progressing in your worldbuilding efforts. "Is this viable" is, *at best,* a question of "will this idea pass suspension-of-disbelief?" Basically, "Is this viable?" means you have an answer to your problem and now you're asking for our permission to use the idea. Frankly, don't ask questions like that.  We're great at answering "how?" We're OK at answering "why?" We shouldn't need to set a rule that says "may I?" is off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Not much in reality.

There is very little use for osmium today because it is both expensive/rare and while hard, it a brittle metal.

Ignoring uses such as chemical catalysts, etc. that would have no application in a medieval setting, it is used to day where the combination of hardness and low-friction makes it worth using.

Assuming that the aliens are dropping off pure osmium metal caches, there could it theory be some applications. But, I challenge your statement the medieval forges could melt osmium. Medieval forge with bellows might reach 1600 C or perhaps a little higher. Osmium has a melting point of 3033 C. I suspect you could probably forge osmium at that lower temperature.

Pretending you could somehow melt osmium, you might find some cosmetic uses where it's unique appearance and composition where give it ornamental value. Rich people made cutlery and tableware out of gold - why not osmium?

Because osmium is quite difficult to work, it would be easiest if this could be used via electroplating - some ancient artifacts have been suspected as electroplated, but most agree a different method was used to get the very thin coating that was observed. The fact that electroplating was considered plausible would indicate to me that you could consider it as a plausible reality in your setting. Certainly more likely than aliens secreting multiple caches of osmium to be discovered. Given the fact that you can't plausibly melt it, I would suggest deciding that they have mastered electroplating it - no doubt a closely guarded guild secret.

It also resists acids pretty well, not as well as platinum, but good enough to be desirable. Coating a tool into osmium would result in a tool that resists corrosion. Would make a very nice mortar and pestle, both for the low corrosion and friction.

Except for novelty value, there is little reason to use osmium in bulk - would make a dandy paperweight, etc. were it not for the difficulty in working it, esp. compared to using lead if all you want is heaviness.

Answer (score 4):

### Coins

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium), the density of Osmium is 1,16 times that of gold.

Even more attractive, Osmium is a very bright and shiny metal.. but it must be hammered to get the shape in, while brittle. You can't melt it, or use it for jewelry.

It will be a challenge. But medieval folks appreciate shiny metals that feel heavy in hand as *precious*. The Osmium is not yellow, so it will probably be valued somewhere between silver and gold. When alloyed, Osmium coins would be very durable, wear-resistant.

When the Osmium left by the aliens is abundant, some metal will be found (eg silver) that can be hammered in as alloy, to make the Osmium less brittle and suitable to stamp a coin.

Answer (score 3):

Osmium is the naturally occuring element with the highest density.

Osmium has a density of 22.59 grams per cubic centimeter.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium

The next most dense element is iridium.

Iridium has a density of 22.56 grams per cubic centimeter.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridium

Thus iridium has 0.99897 the density of osmium, and osmium has 1.0013297 the density of iridium.

Thus for most uses for a dense metal, iridium should be almost exactly as good as Osmium as far as density is concerned.  Other metallugical properties of osmium and iridium may influence which metal is more useful for some purposes.

Are there any dangers in using Osmium?

> Metallic osmium is harmless in its metallic state, but finely divided metallic osmium is pyrophoric and reacts with oxygen at room temperature, forming volatile osmium tetroxide.[74][57] Because all osmium metal slowly oxidizes in air, with the exception of crystallized osmium and various alloys, the degree of hazard comes from its surface area. Some osmium compounds are also converted to the tetroxide if oxygen is present.[57] This makes osmium tetroxide the main source of contact with the environment.
>
> Osmium tetroxide is highly volatile and penetrates skin readily, and is very toxic by inhalation, ingestion, and skin contact.[75] Airborne low concentrations of osmium tetroxide vapor can cause lung congestion and skin or eye damage, and should therefore be used in a fume hood.[23] Osmium tetroxide is rapidly reduced to relatively inert compounds by e.g. ascorbic acid[76] or polyunsaturated vegetable oils (such as corn oil).[77]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium#Precautions

So if an osmium smith produces any shavings or filings, they might spontaneously combust in air, producing deadly toxic gas.

> Iridium in bulk metallic form is not biologically important or hazardous to health due to its lack of reactivity with tissues; there are only about 20 parts per trillion of iridium in human tissue.[19] Like most metals, finely divided iridium powder can be hazardous to handle, as it is an irritant and may ignite in air.[60] Very little is known about the toxicity of iridium compounds, primarily because it is used so rarely that few people come in contact with it and those who do only with very small amounts. However, soluble salts, such as the iridium halides, could be hazardous due to elements other than iridium or due to iridium itself.[25] At the same time, most iridium compounds are insoluble, which makes absorption into the body difficult.[19]

Depending on how the metallugical properties of iridium might be better or worse in various ways than those osmium, benevolent aliens might prefer to give quantities of iridium  to a medieval society instead of osmium.

Comment: +1 *oops* this invalidates at least a part of my answer.. if it is so toxic, there will be risks involved using Osmium to produce coins.

Comment: @Goodies the coins themselves should be safe, but the osmium might be hazardous to the people making them, particularly if the process involves something like powdering osmium and mixing it with gold or making an amalgam with mercury. This wouldn't necessarily stop them though, look up the origin of the phrase "mad as a hatter"...